# Colored rectangles not printing (in PDF nor paper printing)

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, print-design, shapes

So I am trying to overlay colored shapes over a floor plan I've placed in InDesign.

They are just regular shapes (rectangle + triangles) and I filled them with Pantone swatch colors.

For some reason when I export as PDF, I just see the floor plan, and no colored shapes (overlayed). I even tried printing on paper and the color just doesn't appear. 
Here is what it should look like;[image]

Comment: A screenshot of your export dialogue might help

Comment: Might you have set your boxes non printable ?

Comment: Viewing PDFs with spot colors in some *viewers* may be an issue. For example, Apple's Preview application won't display spot colors properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be a combination of using *Pantone spot swatches* and exporting the pdf with a *Standard*.

Normal printers can't print Pantone colors since it requires a separate ink for each color, so if you are not making a file for an 8-color art print you should use RGB or CMYK colors. You can use colors from the Pantone color book, but you have to convert them to RGB/CMYK:

[image: convert swatch]

If you want to keep the Pantone colors as spot colors (and in most other cases) you should try using the *Adobe PDF Preset* called *High Quality Print*. This preset has *Standard* set to *None* which is important because it allows exporting Pantone colors (and other spot colors). I think that you might have chosen a *Standard* which prevents your colors from exporting.

[image: export pdf]